# foreach loop with mysql link table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have 3 MySQL tables, Trophies, Winners and LinkTable I need to output the results in a way that all the previous winners of each trophy will be listed under each trophy because currently each result is just looping giving me a ton on data.

```
Trophies     Winners     LinkTable
--------    ---------    ---------
TrophyID     WinnerID    LT_WinnerID
TrophyName   WinnerName  LT_TrophyID
Description    Year
Image
```

SQL Join is as follows

```
$trophylist = mysql_query("
SELECT TrophyID, TrophyName, Description, Image, WinnerID, WinnerName, Year 
FROM LinkTable
INNER JOIN Winners ON (LinkTable.LT_WinnerID = Winners.WinnerID) 
INNER JOIN Trophies ON (LinkTable.LT_TrophyID = Trophies.TrophyID)");
```

If i output the results through a while loop, as expected returns a new line for each winner with the trophy alongside it.

I think it is a foreach loop that I need to use so that an array can be created for the trophy, but Im a little stuck for ideas now as everything I'm finding doesnt seem to make much sense so anybody pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the `foreach`?

Comment: What's the `while` loop you have so far?  How are you outputting the results?  You can create an array using a `while` loop, too.

Comment: <?php while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($trophylist) ){?>
This is the loop im using currently

Comment: In that loop, just take the values you need from `$row` and add them into the array that you want.

Comment: im sorry but im still stuck could you possibly give me an example ?

Comment: You've not provided an example of your `while` or your `foreach` attempt yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-sort your data into a 2-dimensional array, indexed by trophy and year.

```
$n = mysql_num_rows($trophylist);
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($trophylist);
  $trophyId = $row['TrophyID']; 
  $year = $row['Year'];
  $newlist["$trophyId"]["$year"] = $row; 
}
```

You could then easily use the $newlist array to outputs all winners of a given trophy or all winners in a given year.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can see the array works when I print the array I get all the information, sorry to be a pain but how do I go about displaying this data properly iv never done anything like this before.

Comment: First change the last but one line in the code above to `$newlist["$year"] ["$trophyId"]`.

Comment: Then you could try the following: `foreach($newlist as $trophyArray)
{
  foreach($trophyArray as $yearArray)
  {
    echo "$yearArray['TrophyName'] : $yearArray['Year'] : $yearArray['WinnerName'] <br/>";
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}`

Comment: To get the years in order you should add an ORDER BY clause in your original SQL query.